# MySQL addition of null values

Tags: mysql

I´m doing a query

```
SELECT ROUND((SUM(refracciones.total)+(serviciosrealizados.total)),2)
FROM refracciones, serviciosrealizados
WHERE refracciones.id_ticket = '$idticket' AND serviciosrealizados.id_ticket = '$idticket'
```

2 tables:

1. refracciones
2. serviciosrealizados

2 columns:

1. refracciones.total
2. serviciosrealizados.total

At the moment the query is working but just if I insert data in both table.

I will like the query show me the total of refracciones.total + serviciosrealizados.total if one of the field are empty show me the total with refracciones.total or serviciosrealizados.total

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, say, id 5 is only in serviciosrealizados, this query should do what you want:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(r.total, 0)) + IFNULL(s.total, 0), 2)
FROM refracciones r
  LEFT OUTER JOIN serviciosrealizados s ON r.id_ticket = s.id_ticket
WHERE r.id_ticket = 5
UNION
SELECT ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(r.total, 0)) + IFNULL(s.total, 0), 2)
FROM refracciones r
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN serviciosrealizados s ON r.id_ticket = s.id_ticket
WHERE s.id_ticket = 5;
```

You may have to ignore any null rows.

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83c718/4) as a demo.

You may want to review the database design if possible, as it seems awkward.

Comment: ouch I was testing if is sum just the "servicios" and is not working if I do not insert data in refracciones :(

Comment: is not working
images 

  http://eslumere.elreycalavera.com/img/sql/servicios.png
  http://eslumere.elreycalavera.com/img/sql/serviciosestructure.png
  http://eslumere.elreycalavera.com/img/sql/refracciones.png
  http://eslumere.elreycalavera.com/img/sql/refraccionesestruct.png

Comment: interface

eslumere.elreycalavera.com/img/sql/interface.png